# Have SOLD items removed from Excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Trying to insert formula in all total categories at the bottom so that when something is sold, highlighted in red, the cost/profit/etc is removed from the total. Here is the excel sheet.

https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=Random.xlsx

```
Item    Paid    Worth Today Parts Needed    Worth Retail    Sold    Profit  Markup %    Gross Margin Ratio
2005 Ford GT     $1.70   $6.00       $8.00       $(1.70)    -100%   #DIV/0!
2013 Bently Continental      $1.00   $5.00       $5.00   $4.00   $3.00  300%    75%
1991 Porsche 911     $1.00   $5.00       $5.00   $4.00   $3.00  300%    75%
2014 Volkswagen Tiguan TDI   $1.70   $4.00       $8.00       $(1.70)    -100%   #DIV/0!
2015 Porsche Mecan   $1.70   $4.00       $5.00       $(1.70)    -100%   #DIV/0!
2015 Dodge Charge Hellcat    $26.70      $85.00          $250.00         $(26.70)   -100%   #DIV/0!
1938 Bugatti Type 57C    $26.70      $120.00         $250.00         $(26.70)   -100%   #DIV/0!

Total   Total       Total   Total   Total       
 $60.50      $229.00         $531.00     $8.00   $-
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example speadsheet. We are not going to open some random spreadsheet from dropbox that may contain malicious macros.

Comment: There's the information, but it doesn't show the previous equations. It's dropbox, there's no malware.

Comment: @DavidPostill fixed.